# Concurrency and Thread safety when accessing variable

Tags: c#, multithreading

When writing multi-threaded application, how aggressive one should be with locking class variables? For example, I have a class field that gets changed by one thread only (that runs every second) and is accessed by multiple threads which copy reference to local variable and then use it and can run as often as 1 millisecond.

I am wondering whether or not I can use reference to Data field simply like this:

```
public class OneThread {
    public static DataHolder Data = new DataHolder();
    public void CalledEverySecond() {
            Data = new DataHolder();
    }
}

public class MultiThread {
    public void RunsReallyOftenCalledFromMultipleThreads() {
        Data local = OneThread.Data;

        // now work with local reference

        // I suppose that it won't change and this is legal usage
        // i.e. I don't need to pollute this code with bunch of lock
        // or Monitor.Enter statements
    }
}
```

Of course, I can start throwing lock and Monitor statements, but I am wondering whether or not I really need them in scenario like this. Please answer only if you are able to provide code and have quite some experience with multi-threaded coding - I am not looking into starting another thread that will talk about best practices and theory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no problem with using local reference like that. I've wrote following classes:

```
public class DataHolder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static DataHolder InitRandom()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        return new DataHolder() {Id = random.Next(), Name = random.Next().ToString()};
    }
}

public class OneThread
{
    public static readonly OneThread Instance = new OneThread();

    public OneThread()
    {
        Data = DataHolder.InitRandom();
    }

    public DataHolder Data;
    // this method is called often by one thread
    public void RunsEverySecond()
    {
        Data = DataHolder.InitRandom();
    }
}

public class MultiThread
{
    public static List<string> Results = new List<string>(); 

    // called externaly by multiple threads
    public static bool SomeMethod()
    {
        var loc = OneThread.Instance.Data;

        // initializing new Random every time on purpose since that also takes time
        Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(0,3));

        var id = loc.Id;
        var name = loc.Name;

        var res = loc.Id == id && loc.Name == name;
        if (!res)
            throw new Exception("different");

        var log = String.Format("{0} - OneThreadId: {1}, loc.Id: {2}, id: {3}", res, OneThread.Instance.Data.Id,
            loc.Id, id);
        lock (Results)
        {
            Results.Add(log);
        }

        return res;
    }

    public static void SpitResults()
    {
        File.WriteAllLines("C:\\res.txt", Results);
    }
}
```

To test, I've created Window Form application with two buttons that initialize classes and call them:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _secondTimer = new Timer(state => OneThread.Instance.RunsEverySecond(), null, 0, 2);
    }

    private Timer _secondTimer;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => MultiThread.SomeMethod());
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiThread.SpitResults();
    }
}
```

After running this test multiple times I've got following results:

```
True - OneThreadId: 968900563, loc.Id: 968900563, id: 968900563
True - OneThreadId: 968900563, loc.Id: 968900563, id: 968900563
True - OneThreadId: 1739428491, loc.Id: 968900563, id: 968900563
True - OneThreadId: 1739428491, loc.Id: 968900563, id: 968900563
True - OneThreadId: 1739428491, loc.Id: 968900563, id: 968900563
True - OneThreadId: 1739428491, loc.Id: 968900563, id: 968900563
True - OneThreadId: 1739428491, loc.Id: 968900563, id: 968900563
True - OneThreadId: 1739428491, loc.Id: 1739428491, id: 1739428491
True - OneThreadId: 1739428491, loc.Id: 1739428491, id: 1739428491
True - OneThreadId: 1739428491, loc.Id: 968900563, id: 968900563
```

So, my conclusion is that aggressive locking is simply not needed in cases like this, if I "copy" class field to local variable there won't be any problems - values there won't change and can be used without worry.

If you find any error in my findings, please post comment / feel free to edit.